# 'tuple' object has no attribute 'data'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification

I'm practicing about classifications. I could see `iris` has both attribute when I printed it. But I still getting same error.

```
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

iris = datasets.load_iris(),

X = iris.data
y = iris.target

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)

nb_classifier = GaussianNB()

nb_classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = nb_classifier.predict(X_test)
print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred))
```

[image: Error]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `,` at the end of

```
iris = datasets.load_iris(),
```

Otherwise `iris` becomes a tuple with one element. Your line is identical to:

```
iris = (datasets.load_iris(),)
```